# how to make a day from date in LibreOffice?

Tags: date, time, libreoffice, weekday

I want to convert date into a Day

I am using `LibreOffice`

I used some of its syntax `weekday` and `text` but it returns  nothing

`WEEKDAY("30-04-2019"; 1)` is there any way to do that?

in google sheet i used `=TEXT(C7758,"dddd")` but it didn't work

how can I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the combination of functions WEEKDAY and DATE:

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE(2019;4;30))
```

The specific example will return 3 which is Tuesday (see all days and other options at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_WEEKDAY_function)

Hope that helps.